# Multiple columns from different tables as foreign keys to one column

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, primary-key, guid

I was having a doubt regarding multiple columns as foreign keys to a single column. Let me explain with an example.

Ex: I have 3 tables:

**Company1** : `Company_ID(guid) as Primary key, Address (varchar(25))`

**Company2** : `Company_ID(guid) as Primary key, Address (varchar(25))`

**Employee** : `Employee_ID(guid) as Primary key, Company_ID ( Foreign key referencing from Company1 and Company2)`

**Here the foreign keys for Company_ID in Employee table is coming from 2 different tables. 
This works in SQL server 2008.**

My question is I somehow feel this is not correct. I have never done this in any system, but I was trying this in a sample and it works. I am not able to explain myself that something is wrong here because it works perfectly.

Is my assumption correct or please guide me regarding this ? What is the flaw in the above relation ?

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [Test]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 14:32:32 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [Test] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Test', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.FLEXIQUOTE\MSSQL\DATA\Test.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Test_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.FLEXIQUOTE\MSSQL\DATA\Test_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [Test].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET  DISABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET  READ_WRITE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Test] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table2]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 14:32:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [Company2ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COmpanyAddress] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Company2ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table1]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 14:32:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Company1ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Company1ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table3]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 14:32:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table3](
    [EMployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Company] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EMployeeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_Table3_Table1]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 14:32:32 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table3_Table1] FOREIGN KEY([Company])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([Company1ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table3_Table1]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_Table3_Table2]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 14:32:32 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table3_Table2] FOREIGN KEY([Company])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Table2] ([Company2ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table3_Table2]
GO
```

Comment: Well, the first question would be why 2 company tables?

Comment: I gave this simple example cos I cannot explain you the real scenario. To say, there are 2 tables like this in some legacy system and I can't change that now :)

Comment: You say the foreign keys are "working" in SQL Server 2008 - but I bet you've not actually got foreign key constraints declared in the database.

Comment: Those aren't `guid`s, as most people would understand the term, they're `int`s. And this scheme falls apart as soon as you start inserting data, unless you didn't tell us that there will always be rows in both `Company` tables for any particular ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your feeling is right . . . this is not "correct".  Or, at least, it is a poor design decision.

However, your foreign key relationship is probably a composite key.  In general, you would have another column that specified which table this referred to.  The complication is that this might be an "implicit" column.  So, if one table had US address and the other non-US addresses, neither table might have an "IsUS" flag.  However, the US records would refer to one table and the non-US to the other.

Another issue is how these keys are maintained.  You really do not want to have two tables that have interdependent primary keys.  The typical way to solve this is to combine the two tables into one.

Although this is a bad idea, you might have to live with the structure.  If you can change it, you should.